# iOS is exit(0) Reject

Tags: iphone, ios6, app-store

My application is being rejected for the following Reason, Since its my first App. What Change should i made to proceed.Please provide me some solution?

> 10.1: Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the Apple iPhone Human Interface Guidelines and the Apple iPad Human Interface Guidelines
>
> We found that your app includes a UI control for quitting the app. This is not in compliance with the iOS Human Interface Guidelines, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Always Be Prepared to Stop
>
> iOS applications stop when people press the Home button to open a different application or use a device feature, such as the phone. 
>      In particular, people don’t tap an application close button or select Quit from a menu. To provide a good stopping experience, an iOS application should:
>
> - Save user data as soon as possible and as often as reasonable because an exit or terminate notification can arrive at any time.
> - Save the current state when stopping, at the finest level of detail possible so that people don’t lose their context when they start the application again. For example, if your app displays scrolling data, save the current scroll position."
>
> It would be appropriate to remove any mechanisms for quitting your app.

Comment: Well, wrap your `exit(0);` between `/*` and `*/`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not provide buttons or options for exiting from your application.**

If you do so apple will reject your application.

Also if you call exit(0) from your application at certain point, apple will take it as a crash.

So never do it, your app will be rejected.

Comment: I had an app approved in the appstore that used `exit(0)` as a "feature" but I'll note the app was submitted in 2009.