# Is there a list for iOS app exit codes?

Tags: ios, exit, exit-code

There is global method `exit` which takes exit code and exits the app. I thought that using it was discouraged but then I saw WWDC video where they normally used it.

**Question 1:** I have good reason to actually call `exit` in my app. If I do call it could it cause problems with app review?

**Question 2:** If I call it I would like to pass proper exit code. Where can I find list of exit codes with their meaning?

**Edit:** *The UI of the app is not visible at the time when I would like to call `exit`. **The user will have no way to notice it was called.** So recommendation from Apple's Human Interface Guidelines (not to call it because users would perceive it as crash) does not apply.*

Comment: I am curious: Which WWDC video are you talking of, and what good reason do you have to exit the app?

Comment: Me as a user would still consider it a crash if i switch an app to the background and then want to come back and it is gone.

Comment: @MartinR I think it was one of the videos about In-App purchases. As for the reason - I do not really want to explain it but basically it is a workaround for some serious UIKit bug. UI is not visible when exit is called (see my edit).

Comment: I do not have the App Store rules at hand, but according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13946562/1187415 you must not call exit in any situation.

Comment: @luk2302 I use it in such a way that the user has absolutely no way to notice that `exit` was called. Trust me, you would not be able tell whether it was called or not if you were testing the app just for this. How it is done and why is know-how I cannot share, sorry. What about those 2 questions I asked?

Comment: *"serious UIKit bug"* - you sure? Does apple know about that one? Are you sure you are not breaking something on your side? And of course the user would notice it - either the app remains where I left it, then everything is fine, or it is gone, then it is not fine, what more options do you have?

Comment: Please link to the UIKit bug in radar.

Comment: @luk2302 The app remains where you left it. After `exit` was called. User has no way to notice even if they know what they are looking for. Cannot say how it is done. No private APIs used, no discuraged code exept maybe call to `exit` itself. And that's what I am asking about. No more comments in this direction please. Either you believe it is possible or not but if you cannot help please let others.

Comment: I am **100%** sure that what you are trying will **not** get through review, no need to understand the meaning of exit codes - it will just not get through.

Comment: There are only two exit codes defined in `<stdlib.h>`: EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE. But I doubt that it makes any difference. And `exit()` *terminates* the process, I am pretty sure about that.

Comment: Have you checked what happens in terms of presence of the app in the app switcher? If the app is no longer present in the app switcher after `exit`, it's probably a no-no. Also, this may have detrimental effects on any background modes (background refresh, remote or local notifications, etc.).

Comment: @jcaron Yes I did. It all works as expected - that is as if app was never exited. There is slightly longer delay when you switch back to my app but it is hardly noticeable. My app is not using any features like those you named. Everyone please, I am seasoned for this platform and others, I like to think I am usability oriented and I have tested it for hours. It has no impact on user other then positive. *Can we focus on questions I asked?*

Comment: Well, if you exit on purpose, and it's not due to an error, the only possible exit code is 0. But don't be surprised if for some reason Apple reject it. Have you tried validating the app? `exit` might trigger an automatic rejection.

Comment: @MartinR **Session 305, WWDC 14 around 13:00**, they use exit code 173 to tell the iOS that the app believes it was cracked. That makes me believe there are other exit codes and if one of them might fit my situation I would better pass it. Sure, the app is always terminated - what other point is there in calling something named `exit`...

Comment: @MartinR ...but it does not appear to be terminated to the user. I think that's the important part.

Comment: @drasto: That part in the video clearly mentions that 173 is a special exit code on **OS X**. It is not about iOS.

Comment: @jcaron That is basically my question 1. I am pretty sure manual testing will not discover this as it is invisible to user. But automatic API analyses might. I have to try it - archive and have my API usage validated. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinR What do you do in the same situation on iOS? Your app is paid, it starts, you find out it was not paid for (e.g. Phone is jail-broken). Shouldn't you do the same thing? I have never worked with receips and from that session I only remembered that call to `exit`. So please correct me if I am completelly wrong here.

Comment: @MartinR And even if so - is there any list of exit codes for OS X? I would guess the exit codes might be the same...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html: If validation fails in OS X, call exit with a status of 173. ... If validation fails in iOS, ... Do not try to terminate the app.

Comment: @MartinR I see. Ok, I will see whether API usage validation passes when I add call to `exit`. If not, it is simple. If it passes I guess I will have to decide whether to include call to `exit` it or not.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for all your commnets. They helped.